# Core MIDI: when I send a MIDIPacketList using MIDISend() only the first packet is being sent

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, midi, coremidi

I am trying to send a MIDIPacketList containing two packets that describe controller position change message relating to a x-y style controller.

The function i'm trying to implement takes the an x and y position, and then creates the packets and sends them to the selected target device as follows:

```
- (void)matrixCtrlSetPosX:(int)posX PosY:()posY {

    MIDIPacketList packetList;
    packetList.numPackets = 2;

    packetList.packet[0].length = 3;
    packetList.packet[0].data[0] = 0xB0;        // status: controller change
    packetList.packet[0].data[1] = 0x32;        // controller number 50
    packetList.packet[0].data[2] = (Byte)posX;  // value (x position)
    packetList.packet[0].timeStamp = 0;

    packetList.packet[1].length = 3;
    packetList.packet[1].data[0] = 0xB0;        // status: controller change
    packetList.packet[1].data[1] = 0x33;        // controller number 51
    packetList.packet[1].data[2] = (Byte)posY;  // value (y position)
    packetList.packet[1].timeStamp = 0;

    CheckError(MIDISend(_outputPort, _destinationEndpoint, &packetList), "Couldn't send MIDI packet list");
}
```

The problem I am having is that the program only appears to be sending out the first packet.

I have tried splitting the output into two separate MIDIPacketLists and two making two calls to MIDISend(), which does work, but I am sure that there must be something trivial I am missing out in building the midi packet list so that the two messages can be sent in one call to MIDISend(). I just cannot seem to figure out what the problem is here! Anyone here had experience doing this, or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declaring the MIDIPacketList doesn't allocate memory or set up the structure. There's a process to adding packets to the list. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
- (void)matrixCtrlSetPosX:(int)posX PosY:(int)posY {
    MIDITimeStamp timestamp = 0;
    const ByteCount MESSAGELENGTH = 6;
    Byte buffer[1024];             // storage space for MIDI Packets
    MIDIPacketList *packetlist = (MIDIPacketList*)buffer;
    MIDIPacket *currentpacket = MIDIPacketListInit(packetlist);
    Byte msgs[MESSAGELENGTH] = {0xB0, 0x32, (Byte)posX, 0xB0, 0x33, (Byte)posY};
    currentpacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetlist, sizeof(buffer),
                                      currentpacket, timestamp, MESSAGELENGTH, msgs);

    CheckError(MIDISend(_outputPort, _destinationEndpoint, packetlist), "Couldn't send MIDI packet list");
}
```

I adapted this code from testout.c found [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/articles/linuxmidi/osxmidi)

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answer! I wasn't aware of the need to allocate a buffer and do it this way.. I'm still finding my way through the API's at this stage and I wasn't aware of MIDIPacketListAdd()!

Comment: Apple doesn't have much in the way of documentation for Core MIDI. The book [Learning Core Audio](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands--Programming/dp/0321636848/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362758837&sr=1-1) is the best source of actual usage examples.

Comment: Yeah the documentation seems a little lacking, there is more info to be found in the header files than the documentation I think! I do have that book and it has helped introduce core MIDI but I found the MIDI chapter a little short. Not grumbling though, it is the best info I have found so far! It only explained how to send a single packet at a time though, so it left me assuming that to send two packets together you could build the list in the way I was attempting to in the above snippet. Thanks again for pointing this method out it has really helped me!

Comment: You can call MIDIPacketListAdd multiple times. I could have called it once for each controller message but it was easier to add both messages in one call.